# Does Entity framework by default use connection from the ado.net's pool of 100 (default) connections?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6, ado.net, connection-pooling

Entity Framework uses ado.net behind the scenes.

Ado.net by default maintains a pool of 100 connections with the sql server per connection string (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling#adding-connections).

Thus is it correct to say that each Entity Framework (read/write) query will re-use the connection from the ado.net's pool?

Comment: That's asking something like A > B > C, so A > C?

Comment: Yes trying to understand this including the underlying concept.

Comment: There's nothing to understand about it. EF uses ADO.Net, as you said, how could it *not* use ADO.Net's connection pooling?

Comment: Try this Nuget library to simplify Ado.net code  : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ado.Entity

Comment: So assuming entity framework is used in a windows application being used by 50 users, then will it create 50*100=5000 connections?